# jQuery animate height expand outward instead of down

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, jquery-animate, modal-dialog

I am building my sister a website at [SarahNWatson.com/new](http://www.sarahnwatson.com/new). I have it set up as a big photo/video album. For actual content pages, such as her Bio, I have it so that it opens a modal window.

Right now I have the modal window so that the height starts at 0px and then animates open, however this gives me a slide down effect. I want it to open outwards as if something were in the box pushing in both directions. How can I accomplish this?

Here's the code:

```
function createModal(filler) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var $body = $('body');
                    var winHeight = $(window).height();
                    var winWidth = $(window).width();

                    $body.prepend('<div id="blackout">');
                    $("#blackout").css({ height:winHeight }).fadeIn(1800);
                    $body.prepend('<div id="modal_window">');
                    $("#modal_window").html(filler).fadeIn(2000);

                    var modalHeight = $("#modal_window").height();
                    var modalWidth = $("#modal_window").width();

                    var offsetH = winHeight/2 - modalHeight;
                    var offsetW = winWidth/2 - modalWidth/2;
                    $("#modal_window").css({ top:offsetH, left:offsetW, height:'0px' }).animate({ height:modalHeight });
                }
```

And the CSS:

```
#modal_window {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 600px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: ***...pushing in both directions...*** Which directions do you mean?  Vertical or horizontal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with `offsetH = winHeight/2` and `offsetW = winWidth/2`. Then, animate all of the top, left, and height CSS properties. The final top will be `(winHeight - modalHeight)/2` and final left will be `(winWidth - modalWidth)/2`.

```
function createModal(filler) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $body = $('body');
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var winWidth = $(window).width();

    $body.prepend('<div id="blackout">');
    $("#blackout").css({ height:winHeight }).fadeIn(1800);
    $body.prepend('<div id="modal_window">');
    $("#modal_window").html(filler).fadeIn(2000);

    var modalHeight = $("#modal_window").height();
    var modalWidth = $("#modal_window").width();

    var offsetH1 = winHeight/2;
    var offsetH2 = (winHeight-modalHeight)/2;
    var offsetW = (winWidth-modalWidth)/2;

    $("#modal_window")
        .css({ top:offsetH1, left:offsetW, height:'0px' })
        .animate({ top:offsetH2, height:modalHeight });
}
```

**UPDATE:** Code sample updated to only animate vertically.

Essentially, you're moving the box up as it grows taller. So instead of sliding down it gives the appearance of expanding from the middle.

Comment: Could you revise it to be a bit simpler please? I don't quite get it. Is it possible you could show me the full code? Oh, and I just want the height to expand outwards. Not the width.

Comment: Something's not right in your code. Created a boiled down jsfiddle that works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kNarY/ -- Posted before seeing your comment about working now, but leaving the jsfiddle for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could give it a margin-top of half the ultimate height (modalHeight) and add `marginTop:"toggle"` to your animation:

```
.animate({ height:modalHeight, marginTop:"toggle"})
```

Comment: My calculations were off :P margin-top needed to be 1/4 of the resultant height.  Here's a demo of what I mean http://jsbin.com/eworig

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS setting Bottom instead of Top. You should then use the bottom of the element to position it thus having it animte upwards instead of downwards.

.animate() always animate away from the anchor.